# Connecting dryer to dryer vent

Tags: dryer, vent, exhaust-vent, fire-hazard

In all the youtube videos I see, dryers are connected to dryer vents via flexible hose. One end is clamped to the dryer and the other is attached to a plug that fits into the vent

I bought a vent kit and actually installed it inline with the dryers vent hole.

So I have 100mm diameter metal pipe from the vent kit installed in the wall. Length of the pipe through the wall is probably 160mm

The outside has the supplied gravity louvre in place

Back to the inside:

I put a foam rubber ring (from the kit) over the hole as a spacer

Then I put in a small metal sleeve (from the kit) that fit inside the vent pipe, but then flares / flanges outwards so that there is a round face parallel with the wall

Then I put another ring of foam rubber on that flange

[image: Inside port]

Then I pushed the dryer up tight to that. There's not a lot of room in our laundry so having it tight against the wall is just giving us a bit more room.

[image: Dryer to wall]

I turned it on and the louvres on the outside were definitely opening up as the warm air came through. I couldn't fell any heat coming up from the back

The connection between the vent and the dryer actually looks pretty tight. The distance from the dryer to the wall is about 20mm

I live in a timber home so I'm a bit concerned about fire hazards

- Is it a problem having a dryer that close to the wall? (if it is being vented properly)
- Is there a better way to "inline" a dryer vent with a vent in the wall? Maybe I could trim down the supplied flexible hose
- With dryers, are fire hazards more from lint catching on fire or from dryers getting really hot in a confined space?

At this stage I'm going to inspect after every run to see how it goes

Comment: presumably the exhaust is no hotter than the drum, and the drum is not hot enough to burn clothes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dryer venting properly is a good thing - as long as that is happening you should be fine.

> fire hazards more from lint catching on fire

TRUE.

Clean the LINT out of your dryer after every load - every so often clean out the lint system on your dryer to keep the dryer clean.. I have cleaned my lint system probably 4 maybe 5 times in 20 years.. a good working lint system and you should not need to do it very often. Your dryer will last longer and work better as well.